# How much freedom do I have with media attribute on link tags?

Tags: css, wordpress, performance, optimization

I recently took one of Google's free courses about optimizing for speed, and a new notion was brought up to me about media attributes within the link tag. The idea I guess is to tell the browser not to stop rendering for any irrelevant media queries. I'd like to build a super fast site, but I'm kind of stuck using a bloated Wordpress framework -- forcing me to try to eek out a few optimizations where I can

Is this acceptable?

```
<link 
     rel='stylesheet' 
     id='site-main-400-767-css'  
     href='../assets/css/mainPhone.css?ver=4.8.2' 
     type='text/css' 
     media='screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 767px)' />
```

I'll put it on one line in my source code -- I just think this is easier to read for Stack Overflow.

Additional tips for speeding up a bloated framework?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be acceptable? As for dealing with a bloated Framework: Switch to a leaner one ;). Jokes aside, I've found it's usually harder to strip unnecessary stuff from a fw than it is to add necessary stuff to a simpler base.

Comment: Haha, yea. Right. I'm afraid it's not up to me. I was just wondering if it's okay to USE this optimization that way my CSS is leaner and is only loading exactly what is needed

Comment: It totally is. The primary trade off is development time vs performance. If you're willing to do it, I don't see a technical reason not to, unless you crazy with it and have 50 link-tags (in which case I might, but not necessarily will, change my opinion after some testing).